# Create multiple conditional columns from a source list

Tags: python, pandas

How can I create multiple conditional columns using a list as source in pandas.

This is my original dataframe:

| Treaty Number | Entry Code | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BRI1 | A500 | 2,00 |
| BRI2 | 1100 | 3,00 |
| BRI3 | 1101 | 5,00 |
| BRI1 | A500 | 2,00 |
| BRI4 | A500 | 6,00 |
| BRI5 | 1113 | 1,00 |
| BRI3 | 1101 | 1,00 |
| BRI2 | 1100 | 5,00 |

And this is the list of all the existing entry codes in my dataframe:

| Entry Code |
| --- |
| A500 |
| 1100 |
| 1101 |
| 1113 |

I want to create a column for every single Entry Code with their respective amounts, therefore generating the following output (after aggregating/grouping my data):

| Treaty Number | 1100 | 1101 | 1113 | A500 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BRI1 | 0,00 | 0,00 | 0,00 | 4,00 |
| BRI2 | 8,00 | 0,00 | 0,00 | 0,00 |
| BRI3 | 0,00 | 6,00 | 0,00 | 0,00 |
| BRI4 | 0,00 | 0,00 | 0,00 | 6,00 |
| BRI5 | 0,00 | 0,00 | 1,00 | 0,00 |

I managed to achieve this by creating each column individually using np.where():

```
df['1100'] = np.where(df['Entry Number'] == '1100', df['Amount'], 0)
df['1101'] = np.where(df['Entry Number'] == '1101', df['Amount'], 0)
df['1113'] = np.where(df['Entry Number'] == '1113', df['Amount'], 0)
df['A500'] = np.where(df['Entry Number'] == 'A500', df['Amount'], 0)
```

The problem is I will soon be working with dataframes that contain over 30+ Entry Codes, making it annoying and ineficient to create 30+ individual columns for every single code.

What would be the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just ordinary pivot operation:

```py
# if the values are strings (with ","), convert it to float:
df["Amount"] = df["Amount"].str.replace(",", ".").astype(float)

out = df.pivot_table(
    index="Treaty Number",
    columns="Entry Code",
    values="Amount",
    aggfunc="sum",
    fill_value=0,
)
print(out)

# Note: If you're missing some columns (there aren't any values in the dataframe), you can reindex the columns.
```

Prints:

```
Entry Code     1100  1101  1113  A500
Treaty Number                        
BRI1              0     0     0     4
BRI2              8     0     0     0
BRI3              0     6     0     0
BRI4              0     0     0     6
BRI5              0     0     1     0
```